# How do I import a Powershell cmdlet globally from a function in another module?

Tags: powershell

I'm hitting a problem importing cmdlet globally from a function in another module.

Here is the case. Say I'm trying to call `Test-Method` in an dll.
When I run `Import-Module <dll path>`, things work normally and I can call the `Test-Method` with no problem.

Then I put the command into a function to simplify usage. Now I have something like:

```
function Import-Cmdlets
{
    Import-Module "<dll path>" -Scope Global -Force
}
```

Now in Powershell I call `Import-Cmdlets`, and then I can call `Test-Method` with no problem.

**However, when I put the function into a psm1 file, and import module on the psm1 file, I cannot find `Test-Method` anymore**.

Now I have a `mymodule.psm1` file with following content:

```
function Import-Cmdlets
{
    Import-Module "<dll path>" -Scope Global -Force
}
```

Then in PowerShell I run:

```
Import-Module mymodule.psm1 -Force
Import-Cmdlets
```

Now I cannot find `Test-Method` any more. The dll shows up when I run `Get-Module` and I can see `Test-Method` from ExportedCommands. But I cannot access it.

This only happens for dll imports. I’ve tried to use a psm1 file to replace the dll path, and didn’t meet this issue.

What is a good work around or solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and adding the parameter -Scope Global fixed it

Change your line to `Import-Module <path to your module> **-Scope Global**`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you still don't get the function imported in your other script when doing Import-Module "script.psm1"
is because your "Import-Cmdlets" is not exported.
to export the functions, or any other module members is done like so:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function "Import-Cmdlets"
```

now your Import-Cmdlets will become available for usage.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when importing Cmdlet dll.

Use

```
New-ModuleManifest "...ManifestName.psd1"
```

Edit the RootModule entry to specify the Cmdlet dll.

Then Import this Manifest File and all Cmdlets will be exported (or a subset if you list them in the manifest)

The alternative I did before learning about manifests was to create a psm1 wrapper module that imported the cmdlet dll and then used export-modulemember... Manifest is cleaner but either way you have to create an additional file